# Get matrix statistics ignoring internal matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an image.  I have a sliding window going across this image and that sliding window has a "frame".  Both the window and the frame are defined by rectangles [x y w h].  I know the window is contained within the frame (may share an edge), but I can't assume its location.  I need to get, for example, the standard deviation of everything in the frame only.

For the sake of visualization, assume I have a window (alpha characters) and a frame (numeric characters).  I have a [x y w h] defining each of them.  I know the window is in the frame.  How do I get the stdev of JUST the numeric characters?

1 8 3 8 2 0

a b c 5 2 8

c a b 3 9 9

a c b 0 5 2

9 6 8 3 4 1

Note: in reality this is a piece of an image so everything is numeric.  I just used alpha characters to distinguish the window from the frame.

Comment: If you know the entire picture and you know what is in your window can't you just subtract the window from the picture to get the rest of the picture? Or maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the row and column range of the window within the frame, then logical indexing would be one approach. A self-contained example:

```
frameSize = [5, 6];     % outer [width, height] of frame
windowSize = [3, 3];    % [width, height] of window
windowLocation = [2, 1];% [row, column] of top left element of window
windowRowRange = windowLocation(1):(windowLocation(1)+windowSize(1)-1);
windowColRange = windowLocation(2):(windowLocation(2)+windowSize(2)-1);

% Generate example data: make the 'frame' numbers negative
frame = unifrnd(0,1,frameSize);
frame(windowRowRange, windowColRange) = unifrnd(-1,0,windowSize);
disp('frame:'); disp(frame);

% Generate logical indexes for 'inside window'
insideWindow = zeros(frameSize);
insideWindow(windowRowRange, windowColRange) = 1;

% Take standard deviation of only the outer frame
std(frame(~insideWindow));
```

Outputs:

```
frame:
    0.9961    0.0046    0.3998    0.1818    0.5797    0.3510
   -0.8767   -0.5827   -0.0552    0.2638    0.5499    0.5132
   -0.8161   -0.9503   -0.5091    0.1455    0.1450    0.4018
   -0.7600   -0.0973   -0.5107    0.1361    0.8530    0.0760
    0.9619    0.0844    0.9106    0.8693    0.6221    0.2399

std:
    0.3234
```

The actual numbers will be different, as I have not seeded random number generation.